# GIF created from a movie file with ffmpeg is really large in size

Tags: ffmpeg, gif, mp4

I created a GIF using `ffmpeg` using the following command:

`ffmpeg -i foo.mp4 -ss 00:00:18 -t 00:00:06 -pix_fmt rgb24 bar.gif`

However, the resulting `bar.gif` was over 300 MB in size while the movie file `foo.mp4` was about 15 MB!

What gives?

Comment: have u tried other pix_fmt options?

Comment: @RyanErickson Per the [documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html), I didn't find any useful options. Obv I am overlooking something like you believe. What option would you recommend? All I saw was using the `-window_size` but that didn't quite do the job

Comment: All: Please read the chat transcript by @thirdender, (s)he provided a  very useful [link](http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=2102) in there.

Comment: Also very useful is reducing the gif image size by doing [this](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-242084.html). In other words: 
convert <image> -depth 8 -colors YY -type palette result.gif

where YY<256

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A comprehensive answer to this question is difficult :-p In a nutshell, it comes down to how the compression is done in each format.

In GIF animations, each frame is conceptually a separate GIF image. All of the GIF images are then stored in one large GIF file, with instructions to play the frames back with a certain delay between the frames. To optimize the frames, you can run the GIF through a program that can delete duplicate information from one frame to the next (the GIMP "Animation Optimize" filter is a good way to do that: [GIMP – Simple Animations](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Simple_Animations/)).

On the other hand, video formats like MP4 have a different approach. They assume that frames are going to be similar, and only store the difference between two frames. Additionally, the amount of data for each frame is limited to the specified video bitrate given when you begin the compression. Lossy compression is performed to bring the video file down to the desired bitrate. To further optimize the video file, most video transcoders include options for "two-pass encoding". This runs through the video twice: the first time it just gathers information about what parts of the file are more complex, and then the second time it compresses every not complex portion of the video more aggressively.

There are many other optimizations as part of the video encoding process that are just plain missing from the GIF file format. Also, it's worth pointing out that a GIF animation is going to be limited to a 256-color palette, which can result in image dithering. MP4 uses something more similar to a JPEG compression for the video frames (although with additional optimizations targeted specifically at video… the old MJPEG format was basically just stacks of JPEG images, just as GIF animations are stacks of GIF images).

If you can give more information about your specific use case, we may be able to help you find a better solution.

Comment: What kind of information would be necessary about my use case? Thanks!

Comment: Are you planning to use the GIF for a website? If so, have you considered the `VIDEO` tag instead?

Comment: Yes, the `VIDEO` tag works pretty well in my tests so far :-p Things to watch though… in my Ubuntu 12.04 Chromium browser, things went crashy-haywire if I tried to display a video but gave the browser the wrong video dimensions. Also, the `VIDEO` tag gives you the chance to use some fallback HTML. A lot of people include a Flash based player in the fallback, or just display a static image or animated GIF (which… may or may not help :-p). Lots of good articles about the `VIDEO` tag on the tubes right now.

Comment: so you mean `ffmpeg ffmpeg -i foo.mp4 -ss 00:00:18 -t 00:00:06 -pix_fmt video bar.gif`. I have a ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Hmm… What went wrong with the `VIDEO` tag? Can you [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) the HTML you used?

Comment: I don't have my html yet. I'd like to get all my files ready before I do that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17085/discussion-between-thirdender-and-drn)

Answer (score 2):

i agree with you , using this command is not optimal :

```
avconv -i input.mp4 -pix_fmt rgb24 output.gif
```

Use Gimp as following after this conversion :

[image]

Comment: You then have to choose File > Export as..., choose the GIF format, click export, check "As animation", and specify the appropriate frame delay (which you can get from the layer names in the Layers window).